# Oracle Apex calculate average of column on report

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex

I have CLASSIC REPORT which is aggregation of daily figures. Report present list of predefined dates as list. It is easy to create Total of column, but is it possible to create AVG of column? If not what is the most effective and elegant solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to calculate the average within the SQL for the report using something like ROLLUP.

Another option is to calculate the average with an analytic function (eg AVG(column1) OVER (GROUP BY grouping_column) as column_avg, hide this column but then refer to it in the footer formatting section ("When displaying a break row, display this text before break columns").

You could also do a UNION query and in the second SQL statement calculate your average in the same column position as the column that you are averaging. Then make sure you have one column that determines the SELECT it came from. Use this column as a condition in your report template (Column Template 1 Condition and Column Template 2 Condition)